# iOS master detail 'show detail' segue not behaving like template code

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, master-detail

If you make a new Master Detail app in Xcode, it provides you with a working master detail template. Specifically, when using the iPhone simulator, when you click on one of the master rows the detail view slides in from the right *as if you were doing a `show` segue*.
[image]

If you look at the implementation, however, the segue is actually a `show detail` segue.

The importance of this is that (from what I have seen) `show detail` segues don't provide back buttons, while `show` segues do.

I am running into a problem, where my segues are implemented the same way that the Xcode template segues are, however they are acting like `show detail` segues, and not providing a back button.

[image]

Any idea as to why my segues are behaving different than the example segues?

**Update** Here is a abbreviated version of the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Did you notice that `show detail segue` in template project connected to the `UINavigationController`? I guess in your code you have connected directly to `DetailViewController`

Comment: I have it connected to the UINavigation controller (just like the template). Do you know why the template `show detail` has the `show` animation?

Comment: It is because it additionally connected to `Split View Controller`. If you remove that connection it will work just like your code

Comment: I do have a tab bar in my master view. could that additional layer of separation be causing this? (see updated question)

Comment: Yes. As you know, common pattern is to include navigation controller to each tab bar controller. In your case master controller has tab bar but detail controller doesn't. And in that case it is impossible push new view controller that will hide tab bar of previous controller

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your master and detail controller are part of different navigation stacks.  To get push/pop style animation you'll need to make them part of the same navigation controllers stack.

Try adding a show segue directly from the master table to the detail view as opposed to the detail views navigation controller.  The master tables navigation controller should be able to push the detail view on to the stack in normal fashion.